# Wordpress child theme styles over ridden by parent theme styles

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, customization

I am trying to develop a child theme for the theme designfolio, for that I have created a folder named 'mychild' and put style.css in it like themes/mychild/style.css.

```
/*
Theme Name:     proudeon
Theme URI:      http: //www.presscoders.com/designfolio
Description:    Child theme for the Designfolio theme
Author:         sunilkumar
Author URI:     http: //www.presscoders.com/
Template:       designfolio
Version:        0.1.0
*/

@import url("../designfolio/style.css");
#header {
height: 450px;
border:1px solid red;
}
#header-container, .footer-widget-container{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;     
}
```

But the changes are not reflecting .I have successfully installed child theme and i can edit my child themes style.css from wordpress editor.

I can see the new child styles from firebug inspect element, but it is not active . When I hide parent styles from firebug inspect element , I can see the new styles reflected in the site.

Please help me to find out the issue

Thanks
Proud

Answer (score 1):

Try adding !important in each style line.

for example:

```
#header {
height: 450px !important;
border:1px solid red !important;
}
```

Comment: Adding `!important` to a style rule should be a last resort only. You should read up about CSS Specificity ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity ) because that's a much better way of handling style rule priority.